# How to execute jquery when a variable with a CSS property changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set the scrollleft back to 0 on my wrapper when a specific css property changes. I'm a bit new to jquery and have never used variables, but I'm assuming that I'll need to declare the somewhat complex variable before the function, and then execute the function when the variable changes. Am I correct? It needs to continually respond like this to resize queries. This will be an epic solution for me if it works!

```
var changer = $(".dummy").css("float"); //whatever the float property is

$(document).ready(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if ($(".dummy").css("float") != changer ){
        $(".wrapper").scrollLeft(0);
        }
});
```

Comment: Add `changer = $(".dummy").css("float");` inside your if.

Comment: I have about an hour before I can test this. Is that all? Is code all good and expected to work? I always screw up syntax when writing this stuff!

Comment: That's all I can suggest from the code you've posted. When `float` has changed, you need to update the value of `changer` so next time it changes your if executes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my suggestion: Use an ID for "dummy", if you have more than one "dummy" in your dom-tree you get an array with html elements from jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // First init for "dummy"
    var $dummy = $("#dummy"),
        dummyFloat = $dummy.css("float");

    $(window).resize(function () {
        var dynamicDummyFloat = $dummy.css("float");

        if (dynamicDummyFloat != dummyFloat) {
            $(".wrapper").scrollLeft(0);
            dummyFloat = dynamicDummyFloat;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm struggling to make this code work, or the code I supplied. I have 3 different CSS files that are automatically toggled between depending on browser size, and something isn't working right yet. Thanks for the advice though. I'll be needing to dedicate more time to this one I guess yet!

Comment: Hey this worked! Thanks a lot!!! Cheers to you friend! Now onto the next hurdle..lol!

Comment: Ok after updating this code to be affected by css "color" instead of "float" and combining it into the rest of my code, I'm actually still unable to get scrollLeft to work. Here is my super streamlined code in a jsfiddle. What am I doing wrong? My goal is to have the wrapper snapped back to 0 whenever the color property changes for DUMMY. If you can help I will be so grateful! http://jsfiddle.net/oLqpqxkz/

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have written will work fine.